# Add payable to 0FUCKS

Tags: contract-development, gas, payable

I've been working on building a contract that essentially creates a distributed mortgage as a means of fundraising to pull my parents small business out of probate.

I had started with modifying the ConsenSys until I came across the MiniMe token (I like the idea of restoring lost tokens et c) and found medium.com's 0FUCKS token, (c) Moritz Neto with BokkyPooBah / Bok Consulting Pty Ltd.  I quite like it for MiniMe incorporation and a lack of import.  I want to price it at .01 eth (a penny stock price) and not have to pay for gas after deploy.

I do not want to use a fundraising token tools, as this may be slow growth and does not include repayment with interest.  If another contract would fit my needs better that would be great, but I can't afford to do much in testing or deploy attempts.  My last attempt resulted in my receiving 0 tokens and losing .04 eth.  One of the reason I like the current contract is the address for totalsupply is explicit.

I'm not confident enough to take the abstract/meta example of payable from other answered questions, and I can't afford someone else to do this.

Comment: Short and simple: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To use a token to raise funds to move my family's business out of probate.  The intent is to start buying back tokens after the business returns to operation.  I thought the third paragraph clarified that.  Short and simple:  If that doesn't answer your question, attempt to be more explicit.

Comment: You can use any crowdsale contract to start, for example [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity). You would have to add a buyback option that you should be able to control.

Comment: There is one other technicality to using other people's tools.  I can only afford the small amount of an eth I have in an account, but I nolonger have the json/utc files, and the other tools want to shove everything under the account for metamask's on the fly account creator, and I really only have enough to make one more attempt at a deploy under myetherwallet (I did write down my addy and, I don't know, key?) I didn't even know buy back existed elsewhere, much less that I could bypass the within a certain time limit option of traditional fundraisers. I don't like how any of those are set up.